# Phone won't turn on after attempting to upgrade Galaxy S to ICS

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-s, updates, odin

I tried upgrading my Galaxy S to ICS like I did my Galaxy S2.

I used the exact same steps. However, Odin froze and shut down. So, I unplugged the phone, powered off, and went to power back on in download mode. It didn't show any signs of life now. I've taken out the battery, put back in, but still nothing. When I plug it in, it doesn't even come up with the charging symbol.

Please help.

Comment: Where did you get the update? What update did you use? There's no official update for Android 4.0 (ICS) for Samsung Galaxy S.

Comment: GT-I9100_SEB_I9100XXLPQ_I9100OXXLPD_I9100XXLPQ.tar.md5 is the name of it, I got it from here: http://androidfirmwares.net/PhoneFirmware/Download/27   .... After looking at it, I am seeing that this was for the S2 and not the S... Do you know how i can fix this?    .. This is the youtube vid i watched on how to do it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yhFylo56esg ...

Comment: That file is for a GT-I9100 or Samsung Galaxy S2! Its not meant to be flashed to other models. You've probably bricked your Galaxy S by flashing that update.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I am afraid of! How do i fix it!!?!???!? Can you "un" Brick a phone? Is there some sort of device that i can buy and plug into it to make it work again?

Comment: I'm afraid the mobile is dead... You've flashed a different bootloader, different recovery and possibly you've messed the phone partitions.